# matching headers in fasta files with python

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching, biopython

I have two files: the first is a fasta file with a header and sequence and the second is composed of only headers.

File_1:

```
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4637|10742|1|N|0|TGACCA
TTCCAAAGAAACATGGAAGACCCAGGACTTGGAGGCACCAGGCACCAGCACACAGGGGTA
GGCACATGGCATGGTGTTGGTTGAAGTCTACTTTTCCCACC
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4565|10742|1|N|0|TGACCA
TTAATTTTTTCAGGCAAGTTTTGTGGATTTCAGTGTGTAAGTCTTTCACCTCTTTGGTTA
AATTTATTCCTATGTATTTTATTCCTTTAGATGCTATTATG
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4565|10742|2|N|0|TGACCA
TTAATTTTTTCAGGCAAGTTTTGTGGATTTCAGTGTGTAAGTCTTTCACCTCTTTGGTTA
AATTTATTCCTATGTATTTTATTCCTTTAGATGCTATTATG
```

File_2:

```
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4565|10742|2|N|0|TGACCA
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4668|10746|1|N|0|TGACCA
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4668|10746|2|N|0|TGACCA
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|1|2207|10852|3331|2|N|0|TGACCA
```

I want to match the header in File_2 with anything in File_1 that has the same exact characters up until the 7th '|'.

I split the items in File_1 (each section of the header is indexed into a list). Anyline that begins with a '>' is placed into a variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

#Function, split header line into a list
def getHeaderInfo(blastLine):
   myFields = blastLine.strip("\n").split("|") 
   HeaderInfo = myFields[:6]
   return HeaderInfo

input_file = sys.argv[1]

#Get input file from the command line
inFileName = sys.argv[1]

#open the input file
inFileHandle = open(inFileName)

#loop over the input file line by line
for thisLine in inFileHandle.readlines():
    if thisLine [0] == '>': 
       print getHeaderInfo(thisLine)
       HeaderInfo = getHeaderInfo(thisLine)
```

I have been trying to find a method in which I can compare these same indexes in File_2 to return the following output:

```
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4565|10742|1|N|0|TGACCA
TTAATTTTTTCAGGCAAGTTTTGTGGATTTCAGTGTGTAAGTCTTTCACCTCTTTGGTTA
AATTTATTCCTATGTATTTTATTCCTTTAGATGCTATTATG
>DF94KKQ1|265|D0M1LACXX|3|2103|4565|10742|2|N|0|TGACCA
TTAATTTTTTCAGGCAAGTTTTGTGGATTTCAGTGTGTAAGTCTTTCACCTCTTTGGTTA
AATTTATTCCTATGTATTTTATTCCTTTAGATGCTATTATG
```

Several of the methods I have tried use an index, however, my key is not unique. How can I take the first six elements and make them my key or is there a better method than the current one I am attempting? Thank you.

Comment: The headers lines in File_1 and File_2 begin with '>', they did not appear in the post

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
def make_key(line):
    return "|".join(line.split("|", 7)[ : 7]) + "|"

header_set = set()
with open("file_2.txt") as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        header_set.add(make_key(line))

with open("file_1.txt") as in_f, open("file_3.txt", "w") as out_f:
    accept = False
    for line in in_f:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            key = make_key(line)
            accept = key in header_set

        if accept:
            out_f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

this approach involves memory-mapping file_1.txt, running re.finditer through it to load lines into a defaultdict keyed by header

```
import re
import mmap
from collections import defaultdict
pat = re.compile('>.+?(?=(>|$))', re.DOTALL)
with open('file_1.txt') as f:
    map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

line_1 = defaultdict(list)
for line in pat.finditer(map):
    fields = line.group().split('|')
    key = '|'.join(fields[:6])
    line_1[key].append(line.group())

map.close()
line_2 = []
with open('file_2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
      fields = line.split('|')
      key = '|'.join(fields[:6])
      line_2.append(key)

line_2 = set(line_2)
for key in line_2.intersection(line_1.keys()):
    print "".join(line_1[key])
```

Comment: Thank you I did end up figuring out how to parse both files. Returning the whole fasta record with header and sequence is my next hang up. Will post code soon.

Comment: @user1529819 - the regex solution above returns the header AND the sequence - unless I am missing something

Comment: actually grep ended up working much faster and easier. The issue is file 1 is massive and it is not feasible to read it into memory. With grep I could do the pattern matching after editing the query file (file 2)

Comment: ``map`` is a built-in function, you shouldn't mask it.

Comment: @xApple, not that I disagree with you, but examples from the official docs do exactly that: http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html